# use of undeclared type 'Date' Xcode 9 Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, swift-playground

This is my code in xcode 9 playground

```
class Tutorial: Codable {
    let title: String
    let author: String
    let editor: String
    let type: String
    let publishDate: Date

    init(title: String, author: String, editor: String, type: String, publishDate: Date) {
        self.title = title
        self.author = author
        self.editor = editor
        self.type = type
        self.publishDate = publishDate
    }
}
```

its showing error use of undeclared type 'Date'

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `Date` struct is part of the `Foundation` framework.

Add `import Foundation` at the beginning of your playground.

As a general rule, you should always import at least `Foundation` because many of the everyday types we use are part of `Foundation`. You can also import only `UIKit` (because `UIKit` automatically imports `Foundation`).