# Unable to add the extension

Tags: ios, swift

Well I am new to iOS and i am working on the App. I have added some extension in the project and they are working all fine. But I am unable to add the following extension in my project. and it is giving me error

```
extension Formatter {
    static let iso8601: DateFormatter = {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.calendar = Calendar(identifier: .iso8601)
        formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
        formatter.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)
        formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXXXX"
        return formatter
    }()
}
```

**Error:**

> Use of undeclared type 'Formatter' 
>   Use of undeclared type 'DateFormatter'

Can any one tell what could be the problem ??

Comment: i dont know, in another project it is working as it is

Comment: Add: import Foundation

Comment: this is your answer [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44944220/use-of-undeclared-type-date-xcode-9-swift-4/44944268)

Comment: Are you coding in Swift 2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should import the Foundation framework on top. Because, DateFormatter and Formatter are defined in Foundation Framework.

```
import Foundation
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

`import Foundation`

Should solve the problem, please try doing a clean `⌘⇧K` and Build `⌘B`